# sql insert if exists delete if not exists between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Looking for an SQL Query to do the following:

1. insert all values of column `x` of `table1` to column `y` of `table2` if
   they don't exist in table2
2. delete records from column `table2` if the value of clumn `y` doesn't exist anymore in
   column `x` of `table1`

I tried insert or ignore for the insert query with no luck in sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect fit for an SQL Server [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx);

```
MERGE table2 AS t2
USING table1 AS t1
ON (t2.y = t1.x)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
  THEN INSERT (y) VALUES(t1.x)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  THEN DELETE;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71290/1).

Answer (score 2):

This will insert you all records in Table1, colX, into Table2, colY:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ColY)
SELECT ColX 
FROM Table1
WHERE ColX NOT IN (SELECT ColY FROM Table2)
```

You can't delete all records in a column.  You can however set those to NULL, or if you want to delete the rows, you can do that as well.  Just let us know.

```
DELETE FROM Table2
WHERE ColY NOT IN (SELECT ColX From Table1)
```

OR

```
UPDATE Table2
SET ColY = NULL
WHERE ColY NOT IN (SELECT ColX From Table1)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Merge Statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx%22Merge%20Statement%22)

```
MERGE table2 AS t2
USING table1 AS t1
ON (t2.y = t1.x) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(y) VALUES(t1.x)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```